# Kendo grid how to pass additional parameter from java script

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

in telerik extenstion to pass additional data to ajax request I used

```
function onDataBinding(e)
{
    e.data = {argument : 4};
}
```

where e was div cointainer with data object inside, 
How can I do this using kendo ? I tried the same but for Kendo e arqument is sth totally different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally i got the answer my own and it is :

```
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read({name:value})
```

Comment: Works perfectly but Read() is not a function. It should be read() instead.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Add this to your grid read function or any CRUD operation:

   ```
   .Read(read => read.Action("ReadCompanyService", "Admin").Data("CompanyServiceFilter"))
   ```
2. Add javascript:

   ```
   function CompanyServiceFilter()
   {
       return {
           company: $("#ServiceCompany").val()
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your controller:

   ```
   public ActionResult ReadCompanyService([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string company)
   {
       var gridList = repository.GetCompanyServiceRateList(company);
       return Json(gridList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
   }
   ```

Please note, only string type data is allowed to be passed on read, create, update and delete operations.

Comment: but I am asking how to do it from java script, how to pass it using javascript if I have this var grid.

Comment: to me to understand fully please post the code and describe what you are trying to achieve....

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the terrible late at the party, but i've got some special cake that you may find tasty:

```
function readData()
{
    return {
        anagId: selectedItem.ID
    };
}

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "ajax",
            transport: {
                read: {"url":"@Url.Action("RecordRead", "Tools")","data":readData} 
        }
       [ rest of the grid configuration]
```

I came across this code by inspecting the code generated by Kendo Asp.Net MVC helpers.

I don't know if this is a further implementation that didn't exist at the age of the post, but this way looks really the most flexible compared to the other answers that i saw. HTH

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass some param to ajax request, you can use parameterMap configuration on your grid.

This will get passed on to your Ajax request.

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
    if (operation === "read") {
        var selectedID = $("#SomeElement").val();
        return {ID: selectedID }
    }
    return kendo.stringify(options.models) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Controller", "Action")
    .Data(@<text>
        function() {                                            
            return {
                searchModel: DataFunctionName(),
                userName: '#=UserName#'
            }
        }
    </text>)
)
```

JS function

```
function DataFunctionName() {
    var searchModel = {
        Active: $("#activityMonitorIsActive").data('kendoDropDownList').value(),
        Login: $("#activityMonitorUsers").data('kendoComboBox').value()
    };
    return searchModel;
}
```